# Set FTP User default directory to /var/www Ubuntu Server

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, ftp

Trying to figure out the best way to set the default directory for the few FTP users we have (3 in-house developers who need access simply to the WWW directory).  Want to just set it so that if any of those three logins via FTP they're automatically put into the WWW directory so they can create directories for projects, see existing projects, etc.

Any idea how this is best done?  I've installed vsftpd - but don't know how to set a 'default' directory that FTP users log into.

Comment: Do those users do anything else on that system?  You should simply adjust the home directory for those users to be the directory you want.

Comment: How would I go about that?

Comment: Nevermind - I went into /etc/passwd and edited the home directory there and it worked exactly as intended.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Went into /etc/passwd and updated the home directory for those users to point to /var/www!

Comment: Not how I would do this, but I guess it works. Mind the big security hole you just opened.

Comment: It's an internal server only accessed internally (behind firewalls), with only 2 users who have ftp access to the server.  What is the security hole just opened and what would be the best way to fix it?  Seems silly to criticize just to criticize and not offer any suggestions how to make it better.  I came here and asked the question because I didn't know how to do it - so instead of saying "not how I would do this", explain how you would do it.